# .htaccess and problem with second and more params

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have on hosting in sub-dir named testing these files:
.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([/]*)$ index.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)([/]*)$ index.php?module=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)([/]*)$ index.php?module=$1&id=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)([/]*)$ index.php?module=$1&id=$2&id2=$3 [QSA]
```

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
BEGIN
<?php print_r($_GET);
</body>
</html>
```

js.js

```
window.alert('Alert');
```

Now I launch https://domain/testing - I get popup 'Alert' and this result: Array ( )

After I try https://domain/testing/level1 - I get popup 'Alert' and this result: Array ( [module] => level1  )

After I try https://domain/testing/level1/level2 - popup is missing and result is: Array ( [module] => level1 [id] => level2 )

After I try https://domain/testing/level1/level2/level3 - popup is missing and result is: Array ( [module] => level1 [id] => level2 [id2] => level3 )

Why are GET params seems ok, but when I use second (od more) GET params js.js are inaccessible (or other scripts and linked documents). I need use relative paths only! Where is problem in .htaccess?

EDIT: is solution 'disable url rewrite and use relative paths' or 'use absolute paths' only?

Comment: Try add `RewriteBase /testing/`

Comment: The problem is not your htaccess file, problem is the browser thinks your scripts is in the same directory which it’s requested. A simple solution would adding a forward slash at the beginning of your assets sources (/js.js instead of js.js) which means start at root.

Comment: I know about root - but this project can be everywhere on hosting and I can't use absolute paths

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be absolute paths, another one could be relative paths from the root.

You could also create a subdirectory and put all your assets inside that and add the following rule to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule ^.*assets/(.*)$ path/to/assets/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Which basically is ignoring everything before `assets` and also concatenating everything after it to the new the URL which contains path from the root. 
Also, `RewriteCond` makes sure only the asset files (jpg, png, css, js) get affected by this rule.